# How can I use extension of DbSet<TEntity>

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity, dbset

How can I use `AddOrUpdate<TEntity>(IDbSet<TEntity>, TEntity[])` method that is extension method of `DbSet<TEntity>`. I have no idea how to get access to this method. I found this extension here [MSC Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.dbset-1?view=entity-framework-6.2.0)

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.migrations.idbsetextensions.addorupdate?view=entity-framework-5.0.0

Comment: This method is intended for Migrations only, not for Business operations.
That's why you had to add "using System.Data.Entity.Migrations;" to your code.